# Not able to access the values of a particular column in a dataframe

Tags: python

I am working with a dataframe named as pollution_dataset of which the structure is as follows:

```
date (UTC)              NO2 (ppb)   VOC (ppb)
2020-01-27 07:55:43      147          159
2020-01-27 07:56:43      128          150
```

I am trying to access the first value of `NO2 (ppb)` by writing the following code:

```
for i in pollution_dataset.itertuples():

    NO2 = i.NO2 (ppb)

    print(NO2)  
    break
```

But i am getting error message as:

```
File "<ipython-input-6-44b166fc4d1d>", line 3, in <module>
    N02 = i.NO2 (ppb)

AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'NO2'
```

I don't know why and what is the reason. I am using Spyder IDE for this. Please help

Comment: you can not access the values like this if there is a space in the column name. you have to use it like this `NO2 = i['NO2 (ppb)']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is the whitespace in the column name.
you can try accessing the column via one of the following methods:

```
for i in pollution_dataset.itertuples():
    print(i[2])
    print(i._2)
```

as your row in the dataframe will look like

```
Pandas(Index=0, dateUTC='2020-01-27 07:55:43', _2=147, _3=159)
```